# How to send Push Notifications in OpenFin?

Tags: javascript, openfin

I have to Push Notifications to all the users who are using OpenFin for my site.
As per OpenFin documentation, they have provided API to send a Desktop Notification on an event like button click. But if the OpenFin App is Idle and we need send notifications then how can I achieve that?

I went through the example on this  [site](https://github.com/openfin/openfin-examples-notifications) provided by OpenFin.

Can anyone help with sample code for push Notification in javascript ?

Comment: `But if the OpenFin App is Idle and we need send notifications then how can I achieve that?` as in without a user interaction? Put the notification creation in a websocket subscription or something.

If the app is open but not displayed, the notifications will still be pushed through.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install `openfin-notifications` using `npm i openfin-notifications`.
Once it is installed, import it and use it like Varun mentioned

```
import {create} from 'openfin-notifications';

create({
    title : 'my-title',
    body : 'Any additional content',
    category : 'Event',
    buttons : [
        {
            title : 'Accept'
            onClick : {
            task : 'click-me'
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The example provided in the link is outdated as it uses old Openfin API.
I suggest you to use latest API for notifications
[Openfin Notification API](https://cdn.openfin.co/docs/javascript/stable/Notification.html)

```
fin.Notification.create({
    url: 'https://cdn.openfin.co/docs/javascript/stable/tutorial-Notification.create.html',
    timeout: 3000
}).show().then(() => console.log('Notification created')).catch(err => console.log(err));
```